# KVM PCI passthrough, driver installed but it won't output anything

Tags: graphics-card, virtual-machine, virtualization, nvidia-geforce, linux-kvm

I have a Windows 10 guest VM running on qemu-kvm, with a GTX 970 card passed through to it, using `vfio-pci`. I can start the VM fine and connect to it through VNC, install the nvidia driver, it detects the card fine, I can see the 970 in the device manager.

When I go into the nvidia control panel, it tells me I am not using a display connected to the GPU. Makes sense, since I'm working over VNC, so Windows is probably using some virtual display provided by QEMU.

So then I pass `-vga none` to tell QEMU not to create any virtual displays, and the VM starts up without error, and I can see the PCI device being forwarded in the QEMU console with `info pci`, however absolutely nothing is being sent out the card's video output (either DVI or HDMI, it doesn't matter) to my external monitor. This is driving me nuts. From what I've read on the internet this is supposed to just work at this stage, and I don't know how to continue debugging this.

Has anyone else had this problem of no video output despite the GPU being recognized and the driver successfully installed with KVM? Thanks.

Comment: And of course predictably after posting this I tried again to test something and suddenly I got video output **without** `-vga none`, in addition to the VNC output! This is probably random and just a fluke though, and I would still like an explanation as everywhere I have seen online says to use `-vga none` for PCI passthrough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works although I am not sure why, I have been able to coax the system into working the way I want it to. I'll unaccept this (unsatisfactory) answer if another more comprehensive one comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the timing of plugging in the display to the graphics card impacts the graphics cards ability to detect the display and output through the dvi vs. hdmi vs. vga

I am at the same point you were describing and I only have one DVI display that I'm switching between cards.  I have noticed during boot that the display has to be plugged in to the correct card early in order to see the boot information.  i.e. you can't plug the dvi cable in late and expect the output to be there.

Sorry for the mostly speculative answer, hopefully it helps.